# Y-axis scale in react-apexcharts doesn't update the symbol dynamically

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I'm using [`react-apexcharts`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/) to visualize some financial data. My chart has an option to switch the y-axis scale between percentages and dollars. Although the scale changes correctly when I click on the respective buttons, the axis labels (symbols % and $) don't update dynamically. They only change when I do a fast refresh. Below is a demo:

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;
const Chart = ReactApexChart;

const App = () => {
  const baseChartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'serie1',
        data: [1, 2, 3],
      },
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    },
  };
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(baseChartOptions);
  const [scale, setScale] = useState('percentage');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getYAxisFormatter = (val) => {
      return scale === 'percentage' ? `${val.toFixed(1)}%` : `$${val.toFixed(2)}`;
    };

    setChartOptions((prevOptions) => ({
      ...prevOptions,
      yaxis: { labels: { formatter: getYAxisFormatter } },
    }));
  }, [scale]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h4>{scale}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('dollars')}>Dollars</button>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('percentage')}>Percentage</button>
      <Chart options={chartOptions} series={chartOptions.series} type="bar" width="500" height="320" />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.8.1/prop-types.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/apexcharts@3.42.0/dist/apexcharts.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-apexcharts@1.4.1/dist/react-apexcharts.iife.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The problem starts with how `react-apexcharts` reacts to changes in the options. Below is a snippet of the code that runs when the component props update:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  if (!this.chart) return null
  const { options, series, height, width } = this.props
  const prevOptions = JSON.stringify(prevProps.options)
  const prevSeries = JSON.stringify(prevProps.series)
  const currentOptions = JSON.stringify(options)
  const currentSeries = JSON.stringify(series)

  if (
    prevOptions !== currentOptions ||
    prevSeries !== currentSeries ||
    height !== prevProps.height ||
    width !== prevProps.width
  ) {
    if (prevSeries === currentSeries) {
      // series has not changed, but options or size have changed
      this.chart.updateOptions(this.getConfig())
    } else if (
      prevOptions === currentOptions &&
      height === prevProps.height &&
      width === prevProps.width
    ) {
      // options or size have not changed, just the series has changed
      this.chart.updateSeries(series)
    } else {
      // both might be changed
      this.chart.updateOptions(this.getConfig())
    }
  }
}
```

– [reference](https://github.com/apexcharts/react-apexcharts/blob/c9753f7fd7196e2813a6873681bff481351d9619/src/react-apexcharts.jsx#L100-L129)

From the snippet above, it can be seen that it converts the previous and current options to a JSON string to do a comparison. When the scale changes,  there's a reference to a new formatter function. However, functions get converted to empty objects in `JSON.stringify`, so the resulting JSON strings are the same when compared. Here's a demo illustrating this:

```js
function formatter1() {}

function formatter2() {}

const prevOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'serie1',
      data: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  ],
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: formatter1,
    }
  }
};

const currentOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'serie1',
      data: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  ],
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: formatter2,
    }
  }
};

// Logs `true` even though the options have different formatters
console.log(JSON.stringify(prevOptions) === JSON.stringify(currentOptions));
```

## Solution

### An *ok* solution

With the knowledge of how `react-apexcharts` diffs options, you could add a key to the object that changes when the scale changes to hint to the diffing algorithm that an update needs to occur. In the demo below, `scale` has been added to the `options` object (see the call to `setChartOptions`):

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;
const Chart = ReactApexChart;

const App = () => {
  const baseChartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'serie1',
        data: [1, 2, 3],
      },
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    },
  };
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(baseChartOptions);
  const [scale, setScale] = useState('percentage');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getYAxisFormatter = (val) => {
      return scale === 'percentage' ? `${val.toFixed(1)}%` : `$${val.toFixed(2)}`;
    };

    setChartOptions((prevOptions) => ({
      ...prevOptions,
      yaxis: { labels: { formatter: getYAxisFormatter } },
      scale,
    }));
  }, [scale]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h4>{scale}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('dollars')}>Dollars</button>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('percentage')}>Percentage</button>
      <Chart options={chartOptions} series={chartOptions.series} type="bar" width="500" height="320" />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.8.1/prop-types.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/apexcharts@3.42.0/dist/apexcharts.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-apexcharts@1.4.1/dist/react-apexcharts.iife.min.js"></script>
```

### A *better* solution

Why does `chartOptions` need to be stored in state? You can probably just have it as a plain old JavaScript object. This will simplify your code by getting rid of the code for setting up and updating the chart options state. From [React's documentation](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state):

> #### Avoid redundant state
>
> If you can calculate some information from the component’s props or its existing state variables during rendering, you **should not** put that information into that component’s state.

If you are worried about performance, [`useCallback`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) around `getYAxisFormatter` and [`useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) around `chartOptions` may be useful. However, as with all performance optimisations, benchmarking first is recommended.

With the above, providing a hint to the diffing algorithm that the component needs re-rendering is still required. With the refactor of removing redundant state, this could be done in two ways:

1. Adding `scale` as a key to the `chartOptions` object (in a similar fashion to the *ok* solution).
2. Passing `scale` to a [`key` prop](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) on the `Chart` component. When React diffs the DOM, a change in the `key` hints to React that the component requires re-rendering. This option may be better than the option above because it's an explicit API – if `react-apexcharts` changed its implementation details the previous option may not work. Below is a demo:

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;
const Chart = ReactApexChart;

const App = () => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState('percentage');
  
  const getYAxisFormatter = (val) => {
    return scale === 'percentage' ? `${val.toFixed(1)}%` : `$${val.toFixed(2)}`;
  };

  const chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'serie1',
        data: [1, 2, 3],
      },
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: getYAxisFormatter
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h4>{scale}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('dollars')}>Dollars</button>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('percentage')}>Percentage</button>
      <Chart key={scale} options={chartOptions} series={chartOptions.series} type="bar" width="500" height="320" />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.8.1/prop-types.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/apexcharts@3.42.0/dist/apexcharts.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-apexcharts@1.4.1/dist/react-apexcharts.iife.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ApexCharts doesn't automatically update the axis labels when the chart options change. To make the labels update immediately when the scale changes, you can use a key with a unique value for the Chart component each time you update the chart options. Here's the updated code:

```
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;
const Chart = ReactApexChart;

const App = () => {
  const baseChartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'serie1',
        data: [1, 2, 3],
      },
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    },
  };
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(baseChartOptions);
  const [scale, setScale] = useState('percentage');
  const [chartKey, setChartKey] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getYAxisFormatter = (val) => {
      return scale === 'percentage' ? `${val.toFixed(1)}%` : `$${val.toFixed(2)}`;
    };

    setChartOptions((prevOptions) => ({
      ...prevOptions,
      yaxis: { labels: { formatter: getYAxisFormatter } },
    }));

    // Increment the key to force a re-render of the Chart component
    setChartKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1);
  }, [scale]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h4>{scale}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('dollars')}>Dollars</button>
      <button onClick={() => setScale('percentage')}>Percentage</button>
      <Chart
        options={chartOptions}
        series={chartOptions.series}
        type="bar"
        width="500"
        height="320"
        key={chartKey} // This key ensures the Chart component re-renders when the options change
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

By adding the key prop to the Chart component and incrementing it each time the scale changes, you force the Chart component to re-render with the updated chart options, which will update the y-axis labels immediately when you switch between percentage and dollars scales.